# Unable to use Kendo Ui Controls on my Project

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

I am learning how to use kendo UI controls in visual studio. Previously I was using visual studio professional version, now I have switched over to visual studio express 2012. For some reason html controls don't seem to get converted to Kendo UI controls. There is no error message either. Please let me know where am I going wrong. The code snippet is attached below. Thank You.

```
<script src="telerik.kendoui.professional.2015.3.1111.trial/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="telerik.kendoui.professional.2015.3.1111.trial/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="telerik.kendoui.professional.2015.3.1111.trial/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="telerik.kendoui.professional.2015.3.1111.trial/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>

<body>
<div id="example">

                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="txtFname"     value="" />

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("txtFname").kendoMaskedTextbox({

        });
    });
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#txtFname").kendoMaskedTextbox({  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you load your scripts and css make a difference, try this:

jquery is required to run kendo ui, so it should come first:

```
<script src="telerik.kendoui.professional.2015.3.1111.trial/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="telerik.kendoui.professional.2015.3.1111.trial/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

also the common.css should come before the default theme:

```
<link href="telerik.kendoui.professional.2015.3.1111.trial/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="telerik.kendoui.professional.2015.3.1111.trial/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is in the way you are grabbing the HTML element.

Your code:

$("txtFname") ...

You need to change the above code to like the one below:

$("#txtFname")

Comment: Hi Kashyapa and Gene, Sorry Its a typing error, I already had the '#' in the code, Yet it still does not seem to work.

Comment: i think you have got the answer ... i had not looked at your script reference ... Kendo relies on jquery ... so jquery needs to be referenced first